# how can i get/find android api level 13 emulator option menu?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created android avd emulator with api level 13 and i have implemented sample application on get option menu.But i can't able to find option menu on android emulator api level 13.

Comment: Maybe you should press the menu button?

Comment: yes or any chance to get option menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show up in the ActionBar.(though not as an action view unless you specify)

[image]

Comment: It is showing up only 3 buttons as back,recent,home.But there is no menu button.

Comment: i am running my app in FULL SCREEN MODE.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in your application press option menu button. If you want to do this from your application simply add a button and on the listener on the button call method `openOptionsMenu ()`.

Comment: hey it is working on android emulator api level 12 when i press F2 key.But it is not applicable for api level 13.How can i get option menu?

Comment: I think the problem is that you cannot see these buttons (sometimes this happen if you run your emulator built from source codes). Maybe the problem is in the emulator. Try to create new emulator and choose another skin for it.